# Django-tag shown in the form of writing not in a Django-forms

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using javascript to show a new form every time the user clicks on the button. The javascript code works perfectly, but it only showed me the forms like this {{form}}

[image]

the function in the Django-side code works perfectly

I don't know what I'm missing or what I should add.
This is my HTML file

```html
    <script src="{% static '/js/onclick.js' %}"></script>

    <title>add apointement </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button name="type" class="button1" id="button1">register patient</button>
        <button name="type" class="button2" id="button2">non register patient</button>

        <div id='form'>

        </div>

    </div>
```

And this is the javascript file

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function showAppointementForm() {
    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = `
        <!--<form action="{% url 'create_appointement_register_patient' %}" method="POST">-->
            <p>
                <label for="patients">select a patient</label>
                <select name="patients" id="patients">
                <option value="">-- select a patient --</option>
                {% for patient in patients %}
                <option value="{{patient}}">{{patient}}</option>
                {%empty%}
                <option value="nothing">nothing</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </p> {{ form.media }} {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointement_register_patient">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>
    `
    }

    document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = `
        <!--<form action="{% url 'create_appointement_non_register_patient' %}" method="POST">-->
             {{ form.media }} {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointement_non_register_patient">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>
    `
    }
})
```

These are functions that should work with the forms whenever I click on the button

```py
@login_required
def create_appointement_register_patient(request):
    if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
        form_app = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
        user2 = get_user_model()
        patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_app = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
            if form_app.is_valid():
                form_apps = form_app.save(commit=False)
                form_apps.user_ho_add = request.user
                start_time = form_apps.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_apps.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_apps.patient = request.POST['patients']
                if Appointment.objects.filter(patient=request.POST['patients']).exists():
                    form_apps.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
                else:
                    raise ValidationError('patient does not Exist')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')

            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement_options.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients}) 
        else:
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement_options.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointement"))


@login_required
def create_appointement_non_register_patient(request):
    if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
        form_app = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
        user2 = get_user_model()
        patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_app = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
            if form_app.is_valid():
                form_apps = form_app.save(commit=False)
                form_apps.user_ho_add = request.user
                start_time = form_apps.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_apps.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_apps.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')

            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement_options.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients}) 
        else:
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement_options.html',{'form':form_app, 'patients':patients})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create_appointement"))
```

Comment: Why do you expect JavaScript to be able to render strings like Django? JavaScript is **client side** while Django is **server side**.

Comment: I'm aware of that, what should I add to the Django code or the JS to make it work in a way that when I click on the button it show me the form that work with a specific function in Django code, plz give me a hit that help and thank you for your comment

Comment: It looks like you just want to change the form shown depending on what button is pressed? Why don't you simply render both forms in the HTML. and upon the button press make one or the other hidden?

Comment: If I did that it will show me another problem, the Django code will be confused because there is 2 forms is the same time, one of them for one function and the other for another one, (I forgot what error exactly, but the error that tell you that this form does not exist). That's why I choose to add it using the inner html of JS, thanks again for your proposition